# Dynamic tables printing wrong row and columns in html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically generate a table on my website but it's giving me the wrong rows(width) and column(height)

For an input of `row=1` and `column=4` it generates a tables of 2 rows with 1 row of 5 columns and the other with 4 columns

```js
$("#sizePicker").submit(function(event) {
  var height = event.currentTarget[0].value,
    width = event.currentTarget[1].value;

  console.log(height + "width" + width);

  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    $('#pixelCanvas').append("<tr>");
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      console.log(j);
      $('tr').append("<td></td>");
    }
    $('#pixelCanvas').append("</tr>");
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
  <input id="click" type="submit">
</form>
<table id="pixelCanvas">

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you append `td` to every `tr` that is in `table`.

This is **wrong**

**Here is an working example**

```js
$("#sizePicker").submit(function(event) {
  var table = $('#pixelCanvas'),
    height = event.currentTarget[0].value,
    width = event.currentTarget[1].value;

  console.log("height: " + height + ", width: " + width);
  
  table.html("");

  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    table.append("<tr class='row" + i  +"'></tr>");
    
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      $("tr.row" + i).append("<td>" + i + j + "</td>");
    }
   
  }
  
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="4"> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="5">
  <input id="click" type="submit">
</form>
<table id="pixelCanvas">

</table>
```

Comment: I thought it referenced only the current tr since it was in the for loop but i guess Jquery looks at all the elements. Thank you!.
Also i see you've hidden the sizepicker after 1 submit . Is there any way i could delete the old table on a new input by the user?

Comment: @Glen I changed that, try now

Comment: @Glen jQuery selector e.g. `$(".class")` works the same way as css. So `$("tr")` will refer to all `tr` on page. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

According to your logic `td` goes on appending inside every `tr` as loop goes. So you need to append `td` to this `tr` not on all `tr` inside `table`. Here is an working example.

```js
$(function() {
$("#click").on('click', function(event) {
    var height  = $('#inputHeight').val();
    var width = $('#inputWeight').val();
    var html = '';
    for (var i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        html +='<tr>';
        for (j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            html+= "<td>"+i + '' + j+"</td>";
        }
    html += ("</tr>");
  }
  $('#pixelCanvas').html(html);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input id="click" type="button" value="submit">
    </form>
 <table id="pixelCanvas">


    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you append a new `td` to every `tr` that exists in the table, even those created in previous iterations.

You can fix this, and improve the logic, by creating arrays containing the `td` and `tr` elements based on the extents specified in the input values. Something like this:

```js
$("#sizePicker").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var height = parseInt($('#inputHeight').val(), 10);
  var width = parseInt($('#inputWeight').val(), 10);  
  
  var columns = new Array(width).fill('<td></td>').join('');
  var rows = new Array(height).fill(`<tr>${columns}</tr>`);
  
  $('#pixelCanvas').html(rows.join(''));
});
```

```css
table { 
  margin: 10px;
}
table td {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height: <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="5"><br />
  Grid Width: <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="5"><br />
  <input id="click" type="submit">
</form>
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in your script, this is how the submit function should look like:

```
$("#sizePicker").submit(function(event) {
 height = parseInt(event.currentTarget[0].value),
 width = parseInt(event.currentTarget[1].value);

 console.log(height + "width" + width);

 for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) 
 {

  if(height>0)
  {
    let tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) 
    {
     tr.append("<td></td>");
    }
    $('#pixelCanvas').append(tr);
  }
 }

 event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This makes the tr and td elements separate rather than parent child

Comment: @Glen You are right, I update the answer to a working solution